# Get dropdownlist selected value to autocomplete in JavaScript and asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a text box:  txtBillNo
And a dropdownlist: ddlFiscalYear

And a property:

```
   public int NUM_FISCALYEAR_ID
    {
        get { return Common.ParseInt(ddlFiscalYear.SelectedValue); }
    }
```

And I use the following javascript:

```
  $("#<%=      
     txtBillNo.ClientID%>").autocomplete("AdvanceDDL.aspx?SearchBy=expensebudgetid/" + document.getElementById('<%= ddlFiscalYear.ClientID%>').value, {
    width: 200, selectFirst: true
     });

    $("#<%= txtBillNo.ClientID%>").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        if (data)
            document.getElementById('<%= hfExpenseBudgetID.ClientID%>').value = data[1];
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= hfExpenseBudgetID.ClientID%>').value = '';
            document.getElementById('<%= txtBillNo.ClientID%>').value = '';
        }
    });
    $("#<%=txtBillNo.ClientID%>").blur(function() {
        $(this).search();
    });
```

but `document.getElementById('<%= ddlFiscalYear.ClientID%>').value` always getting 0.

Comment: plese checi it once by placing alert() statement before you passing value to autocomplete() method

Answer (score 0):

to get the value from the dropdownlist please you use the following code

1. need to get the selected index first and then
2. get the value of the selected index from the oprions array of a particular dropdownlist as follows

javascript :

**var IndexValue = document.getElementById('<%= ddlFiscalYear.ClientID%>').selectedIndex;**

**var SelectedVal =document.getElementById('<%= ddlFiscalYear.ClientID%>').options[IndexValue].text**;

let me know the status

Comment: var IndexValue = document.getElementById('<%= ddlFiscalYear.ClientID%>').selectedIndex;

        var SelectedVal = document.getElementById('<%= ddlFiscalYear.ClientID%>').options[IndexValue].text;
        $("#<%= txtBillNo.ClientID%>").autocomplete("AdvanceDDL.aspx?SearchBy=expensebudgetid/" + SelectedVal, {
   
            width: 200, selectFirst: true
        });  But till passing 0